# Counting data that is valid to two conditions in columns 1 and 2

Tags: unix, if-statement, awk, csh

I am trying to run the following loop, the two while statements work, but the @ c awk line seems to be causing me some problems.

```
printf "" >! loop.txt

@ x = -125
while ($x <= -114)
    @ y = 32
    while ($y <= 42)
        @ c =`awk '{ for ($1 = $x*; $2 = $y*){count[$1]++}}' text.txt`
    printf "$x $y $c\n" >> loop.txt
    @ y++
    end
@ x++
end
```

With the awk line, I am trying to reference a file with lots of differing values in columns 1 and 2 of the text.txt file. 
I want to be able to firstly reference all of the values in column 1 that start with $x (as they all have several decimal places), then reference from that sub-list all of the values in column 2 that begin with $y. After this second sub-list has been formed, I would like to count all of the entries valid to those conditions.
However, I keep getting syntax errors with the line, and I'm not sure that I'm using the correct function!

EDIT:

The executable file is a .csh type (C shell, I think)

A sample input format...

```
-125.025 32.058 2.25
-125.758 32.489 2.67
-125.349 32.921 3.49
-125.786 32.753 4.69
-125.086 33.008 2.78
```

And the expected output...

```
-125 32 4
-125 33 1
```

Comment: @EdMorton I'm working within a UNIX environment, and using .csh executable files - unfortunately I can't offer much more information, we weren't told much about what we're using, just the basics of using it...

Comment: @EdMorton From one of our resources, it says "At NOCS you will use the csh and tcsh, so-called because they have a certain amount of C-like syntax."
It is only really the awk line that I need to try to get to work

Comment: That language is neither C shell nor tcsh AFAIK. You should not use [t]csh for scripting anyway as that is not what it is for (google "Csh why not") and any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you are doing the wrong thing (google that too). A UNIX shell is an environment from which to call tools with a language to sequence those calls, that is all. The UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. Your whole problem should be solved with one trivial awk script.

Comment: believe or not, `@ y++` etc. is valid csh syntax (just checked). The unanswered question from O.P. is what is `for ($1 = $x*; $2 = $y*)` supposed to be doing? You'd need to allow the values of `$x and $y` be passed into the `awk` script to have them be meaningful (the single quotes on the awk script prevent them from being expanded to their shell value). And of course, cycling thru the whole file for each record doesn't seem like a good idea. Learn `awk`! Good luck to all.

Comment: As you say 'the @ c awk line ... causing problems', be sure there is a space on both sides of the equal sign, i.e. `@ c = awk '{ ....}'` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

So this is all you want?

```
$ awk '{cnt[int($1)][int($2)]++} END{for (x in cnt) for (y in cnt[x]) print x, y, cnt[x][y]}' file
-125 32 4
-125 33 1
```

If you want to specify a range of x and y values, just add that range check before incrementing the array entry:

```
awk '
    { x=int($1); y=int($2) }
    x>=-125 && x<=-114 && y>=32 && y<=42 { cnt[x][y]++ }
    END { for (x in cnt) for (y in cnt[x]) print x, y, cnt[x][y] }
' file
```

I spit it into multiple lines to improve readability and added variables to avoid calling `int()` multiple times for each field.

Note that the above will read your input file just once compared to the script you posted in your question which will read the whole input file 132 times so you can imagine the performance improvement from that alone, never mind all the starting/stopping processes 132 times, etc.

The above use GNU awk for 2D arrays but can be easily simulated with other awks.